# $20$ students takes an exam what is the possibilities to grade them while between each two students the gap between grade is $4$

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following question :

$20$ students takes an exam what is the possibilities to grade them while between each two students the gap between grade is $4$.

The grades are between $0-100$.

**This is what I did :**

$$20!*CC^{25}_{21}$$

$20!$ - The students are different so the order between them matters.

$CC^{25}_{21}$ - we have total of 101 grades possible, between each two student the gap must be at least $4$ so lets use the ball and cells methods, we have 21 cells while two of them (the one after the max grade, the one after the min grade) doesn"t matter. so we get $101-19*4=25$ so we have $25$ ball into $21$ cells.

For some reason the this answer is wrong, The answer is $$20!*CC^{24}_{21}$$
I don't understand why my answer is wrong.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does "the gap between grade is $4$" mean that two students getting scores of $1$ and $5$ is possible, or not?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: 25 balls into  21 cells (you can put more than 1 ball or 0 balls in each cell) is ${25+21\choose 21}

Comment: the right answer is what i wrote in the bottom meaning 24 balls to 21 cells unlike my answer for some reason which i dont understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is totally fine. But as the devil is in the detail, I would like to have your attention on the "bar and balls" part. You have $101$ balls (grades) and $20$ bars (students). If a bar is put in front of the ball number $i$, then the grade, associated with that bar is $i$. Firstly, a bar can be put in a place where there is at least one ball in front of it. otherwise a student would be assigned to grade $102$. There are $20$ students, which means that we need $21$ cells ($x_1,x_2,...,x_{21}$). The last cell should have at least $1$ ball in it ($x_{21}\geq$1). For $x_1$ there is no limit. For other cells, we should have $x_j\geq4$. So the problem is

$x_1+x_2+...+x_{21}=101-1-4\times19=24$

Comment: why is this true? a bar can be put in a place where there is at least one ball in front of it. otherwise a student would be assigned to grade 102.

Comment: This is just my way of modelling the problem. we have 101 possible grades, which we want to show by 101 balls. A student is a bar and if we put a student in front of ball $i$, it means the grade, that assigned to the student, is $i$. Now, if we put a bar at the end of the row of balls and bars, which means there is no ball in front of it, then the bar (student) would be assigned to no grade.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't subtract off the top student (or bottom student) - your available balls for the floating grade points are $101-19\times \color{blue}{4} \color{red}{-1} = 24$, going into the $21$ cells among and around the students grade zones. The $19$ sets of $\color{blue}{4}$ grades are pre-allocated to preserve a student grade plus nearby grades above and the $\color{red}{1}$ other grade point to exclude is the top student.